# Viber share button throws exception in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, viber

I am developing and Android app. In my app, I am add Viber share feature. So I searched online "How to share a content with viber in android". Then I found Viber for business. So for share button, I followed this link, https://www.viber.com/en/viber-share-button. As you can see, it is so simple. It is just asking to redirect to browser with a url. So I open a browser with url to share on viber as follow.

```
   private void shareOnViberClick()
        {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("viber://forward?text=textIWantToShare"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
```

But when I click share button and call that method, it throws following error

```
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=viber://forward?text=မန္ယူအသင္း၏ ပရိတ္သတ္ဟုထုတ္ေဖာ္ေျပာျပခဲ့သည့္ ေဒါ့မြန္လူငယ္ၾကယ္ပြင့္ }
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3390)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:842)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3587)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3555)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at tonightfootballreport.com.tfr.NewsDetailsActivity.shareOnViberClick(NewsDetailsActivity.java:364)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at tonightfootballreport.com.tfr.NewsDetailsActivity.access$200(NewsDetailsActivity.java:47)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at tonightfootballreport.com.tfr.NewsDetailsActivity$4.onClick(NewsDetailsActivity.java:134)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-07 05:33:02.357 11715-11715/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-07 05:33:02.637 11715-11830/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 601K, 8% free 9230K/10032K, paused 56ms, total 60ms
09-07 05:33:05.029 11715-11833/tonightfootballreport.com.tfr D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 258K, 6% free 10866K/11548K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
```

Why is that error thrown? Is the Viber share API I am following correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no guarantee there's activity with `intent-filter` matching your requirements, therefore `startActivity()` can fail and this should be handled in your code. If that happens it throws `ActivityNotFoundException`, so simply wrap your `startActivity()` with `try/catch`

Comment: Ah. But it throws exception all the time. So it means like Viber Share is not working at all?

Comment: No, it means exactly what I said - there's no app on that device with Activity having `intent-filter` to handle your `viber://forward?text=textIWantToShare`. So either you need to do have something different for Viber to handle it? You may use this tool: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.ashtonbrsc.android.intentintercept to see what are other app sending that works

Comment: Oh. Thank you. Yes, my device does not have Viber installed.

Comment: So the only solution for you is either add dialog to let user know there's no Viber installed (perhaps with button linking directly to Play store) or you can try sharing in less app specific way, so user will be able to choose which app s/he wants to use. If that answers your question, please  [accept it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: Ok. Thank you for support.

Answer (score 1):

> `If you prepend http:// may be problem solved.`

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
```

> `Like in your case may be work around with viber url`.

```
Uri.parse("http://viber:forward?text=textIWantToShare")
```

**EDIT 1:**

`May be they are using this url scheme only for web we not be able to use it through our app.`

> `So may be you can do this way.`

```
boolean found = false;
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("text/plain");

        // gets the list of intents that can be loaded.
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                .queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
        if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
            for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase(
                        Locale.getDefault()).contains("com.viber.voip")
                        || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase(
                                Locale.getDefault()).contains("com.viber.voip")) {
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your text to share");
                    share.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                    found = true;
                    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {

                displayToast(context, "Install viber android application");
                Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id="
                        + "com.viber.voip");
                Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
                context.startActivity(marketIntent);
            }

        }
```

> `And also whatever Marcin sir have suggested in his answer`.

Comment: But Viber is supposed to use only this url schema, viber://forward?text=.

Comment: @WaiYanHein May be they are using this *url scheme* only for web we not be able to use it through our app.

Comment: @WaiYanHein Check my edited answer for different approach.

Answer (score 0):

It means the device don't have any intent to launch the current specified intent. So, please check the condition (smsIntent.resolveActivity(mPackageManager) != null) so that we can show any message to user

try to use

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setPackage("com.viber.voip");
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Message body");
```